# What is done in IntelliJ "Make" phase?

Tags: android, intellij-idea

Running an Android project in IntelliJ seems to be much slower than in Eclipse. It sometimes does this "Make" for tens of seconds:

[image: IntelliJ status bar]

This is before compiling Java sources or even DEX-ing.

What actually happens in this "Make" phase? Is this checking the filesystem for modified files?

(on Mac OS X 10.9.1 with ~5.5 GB free RAM)

Answer (score 1):

- **Make Project** 
  All the source files in the entire project that have been modified since the last compilation are compiled. Dependent source files, if appropriate, are also compiled. Additionally, the tasks tied to the compilation or make process on modified sources are performed. For example, EJB validation is performed if the corresponding option is enabled on the Validation page.
- **Make Module** 
  Compiled are all the source files that have been modified since the last compilation in the selected module as well as in all the modules it depends on recursively.

You can check this link out ,

https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/compilation-types.html

Comment: What I meant was the "Make"  status as shown in the screenshot, not the Make command. The Make command causes the Make status and other statuses like compiling sources, pre-dexing and packaging (for Android projects)